# Error "The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. " update method

Tags: laravel, edit, patch

Well hello there, I am trying to update a register of  my table assistants, but when I push the button submit of the form, this error appear, I am using a table pivot between assistants and events, but i am only try to edit a assistant.[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j90L8.png)

This is my code AssistantController.php file and the methods edit and update

[edit and update methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMDHj.png)

```
 public function edit(Assistant $assistant)
{   
    #obtain id assistant
    $assistant_id = $assistant->id;
    #get data event of the assistant to pass to the form
    $event = Assistant::find($assistant_id)->events()->get();
    return view('assistants.edit',compact('assistant','event'));
}


public function update(Request $request, Assistant $assistant)
{   
    #updating
    $assistant->update($request->all());        
    //$assistants->user()->associate(Auth::user());
    //
    #obtain id assistant
    $assistant_id = $assistant->id;
    #get data event of the assistant to pass to the form
    $event = Assistant::find($assistant_id)->events()->get();
    return redirect('assistants.index',compact('assistant','event'));
}
```

This is my form to assistants
[input form assistants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ye6.png)

```
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">Document:</label>
    <small class="text-muted">Required(*)</small>                                                                
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm "  value="{{ old('id') ?? $assistant->id }}" name="id" autofocus>    
    <div>{{ $errors->first('id') }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <small class="text-muted">Required(*)</small>                              
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm "  value="{{ old('name') ?? $assistant->name }}" name="name" placeholder="First Name assistant">                                    
    <div>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
    <small class="text-muted">Required(*)</small>                                  
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm "  value="{{ old('last_name') ?? $assistant->last_name }}" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name assistant">
    <div>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <small class="text-muted">Required(*)</small>
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm " value="{{ old('phone') ?? $assistant->phone }}" name="phone">
    <div>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                                         
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <small class="text-muted">Required(*)</small>
    <input type="mail" class="form-control form-control-sm " value="{{ old('email') ?? $assistant->email }}" name="email">
    <div>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                        
    <label for="observations">Observations:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " value="{{ old('observations') ?? $assistant->observations }}"name="observations">
    <div>{{ $errors->first('observations') }}</div>
</div>
```

This is my edit page

```
   @extends('layouts.back')

@section('title','Edit assistants')

@section('content')
<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                <h3>Edit details to assistant:</h3><br>
                <h4><strong> {{$assistant->name}} {{$assistant->last_name}}</strong> </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/assistants" method="POST">
                    @method('PATCH')
                    @include('assistants.form')                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    <a href="{{@route('assistants.index',[id=>$event[0]])}}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>            
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

</div>   
@endsection
```

There are my routes
[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9P6h.png)

```
 Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('events', 'EventController');
Route::resource('assistants', 'AssistantController');
Route::resource('certificates', 'CertificateController');
Route::resource('signers', 'SignerController');
```

I am beginner.

thank you all.

Comment: hi, it would be much better you posted your code directly rather than images

Comment: Thanks, I 'll keep it in mind!, I'm a stack overflow beginner too. sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your edit page, change your form action from

```
<form action="/assistants" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="/assistants/{{ $assistant->id }}" method="POST">
```

Without the assistant id in the action field, Laravel thinks you are trying to update the base assistants route, which is an invalid action for that route.